# jQuery Post eventData

Tags: jquery, post

I'm building a web app using jQuery and am following a pseudo-MVC model.  I have the following methods:

```
function Controller() {
    this.view = new View(this);
    $(window).resize(this, function (event) {
        event.data.view.screenResize();
    });
    this.getImages();
}

Controller.prototype.getImages = function () {
    this.view.showMessage('Getting Available Images');
    $.post("../async", {cmd: 'getimages', data: ''}, function(data) {
        this.view.showMessage('Found Images');
    });
}
```

However, the `this.view.showMessage()` inside the `$.post()` does not work because the `this` now refers to the jQuery postback, rather than the controller.  I was able to get around this in the `$(window).resize()` method by passing in the controller as the eventData, but I don't see this for `$.post()`.  Is there someway to reference the original controller and the subsequent view from inside the post function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in scope of the callback function, so `this`points to it. Try this:

```
Controller.prototype.getImages = function () {
    var $this = this;
    this.view.showMessage('Getting Available Images');
    $.post("../async", {cmd: 'getimages', data: ''}, function(data) {
        $this.view.showMessage('Found Images');
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple!  Thanks!